# remove parentheses from array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove parentheses only if they are in the beginning and the end of a given sting :

Example :

`$test = array("(hello world)", "hello (world)");`

becomes :

`$test = array("hello world", "hello (world)");`

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and what issues that attempt had. Also, you need to fully define the problem - for example, do you need to match opening and closing braces? What happens if there are multiple braces `((hello) world)`, or mismatched `(hello) world)` `))hello() world()` etc

Answer (score 4):

Try this, using [`array_map()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with an [anonymous function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), and [`preg_replace()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$test = array("(hello world)", "hello (world)");
$test = array_map(function($item) {
    return preg_replace('/^\((.*)\)$/', '\1', $item);
}, $test);
```

For example:

```
php > $test = array("(hello world)", "hello (world)");
php > $test = array_map(function($item) { return preg_replace('/^\((.*)\)$/', '\1', $item); }, $test);
php > var_dump($test);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "hello world"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "hello (world)"
}
php >
```

As [@revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) pointed out in the comments, we can also modify the array in place to increase performance and reduce memory usage:

```
array_walk($test, function(&$value) {
    $value = preg_replace('/^\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $value);
});
```

Comment: FYI Instead of doing a `array_map()` and storing modified cloned array to the same variable `$test`, you may use a `array_walk()` with a pass-by-reference argument.

Comment: I can't think of a good way to modify it in place without having the keys as well. We'd have to use `array_walk()` as theres no good way to pass the keys by reference.

Comment: I didn't get you thoroughly, but you don't need to pass keys at all.

Comment: Ahh, hmm, do you mean `array_map(function($item) use (&$test) { $item = preg_replace(...); }, $test);`?

Comment: What's its purpose?! That doesn't seem right to me. I just offered `array_walk` over `array_map` in your case: `array_walk($test, function(&$value) { $value = preg_replace('#^\((.*)\)$#', '$1', $value); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace` with `array_map`:

```
$test = array("(hello world)", "hello (world)");

$finalArr = array_map(function($value) {
    return preg_replace("/^\((.*)\)$/", "$1", $value);
}, $test);

print_r($finalArr);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello world
    [1] => hello (world)
)
```

---

Remember: It will leave out, `(hello world` or `hello world)`

Comment: @Rizier123 No. Read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

For example

```
<?php
$test = array("(hello world)", "hello (world)");

foreach ($test as &$val) {
     if (preg_match("/^\(.*\)$/",$val)) {
        $val = substr($val,1,-1);
     }
}

print_r($test);
```

Prints:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => hello world
>       [1] => hello (world)
>   )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// if first character = "(" AND last character = ")"
if (substr($string, 0,1) == "(" && substr($string, 0,-1) == ")") 
{
    $string = substr($string, 1);
    $string = substr($string, 0,-1);
}
```